# recvfrom() error 10035 using non-blocking sockets

Tags: c, sockets, visual-studio-2008, networking, error-handling

I am using ioctlsocket() function to make my socket non-blocking but when I call recvfrom(), I get the error 10035 (`WSAEWOULDBLOCK`).

```
u_long mode = 1;
ioctlsocket(newSocketIdentifier, FIONBIO, &mode);

while(1)
   {
      if((recv_len = recvfrom(newSocketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      {
         char err[128];
         itoa(WSAGetLastError(),err,10);
         MessageBox( NULL,"Could not Receive Data",err,MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         BREAK;
      }
   }
```

Can anybody explain why this happens? :(

Comment: I/O calls can fail. Are you sure you *succeed* as making the socket non-blocking?

Comment: You get WSAEWOULDBLOCK on a non-blocking socket if there is currently no data available. That is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is normal if no data is available.  The code is WSAEWOULDBLOCK (see this table) and means, that on a blocking port the function would have to sit and wait until it could be served.

```
   while(1)
   {
      if((recv_len = recvfrom(newSocketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
      { 
         int ierr= WSAGetLastError();
         if (ierr==WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {  // currently no data available
             Sleep(50);  // wait and try again
             continue; 
         }

         // Other errors
         char err[128];
         itoa(ierr,err,10);
         MessageBox( NULL,"Could not Receive Data",err,MB_ICONINFORMATION);
         break;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I the Client is continuously reading data from a text file and sending over the socket then how come there is no data available to be read? :(

Comment: Any short loop as yours will be faster than packets arriving over the network.  If you get the WSAEWOULDBLOCK just put your loop to sleep for a few milliseconds (e.g. Sleep(50)) and continue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now with Sleep()s but do you think its a good approach? Initially I was using WSAWaitforMultipleEvents() to make a call to recvfrom() only when FD_READ Event became available. I thought it was similar to non-blocking sockets but then somebody gave me the idea of using ioctlsocket().

Comment: The sleep is a clumsy solution.  Normally you use select() (or maybe WSAWaitforMultipleEvents()) to wait for data available, then try to read.  Or just use a blocking socket which will do the waiting in the best possible way for you.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but according to my understanding, if using ioctlsocket() if there is no data to be read, recvfrom() function doesnot block and simply exits without any error :( Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot agree that this is "normal" like posted above.

In your call of `recvfrom` you will receive an error in `recv_len`. I recommend to check that value - it will be `SOCKET_ERROR` and by calling `WSAGetLastErrorenter` you will see error `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.

I am not a (Windows) socket expert, but based on my tests, I cannot use combination of `ioctlsocket` and `recvfrom` for receiving data via UDP in non-blocking mode (I did the same thing like you in your example).

I am planning to use combination of `select` and `recvfrom` with minimum possible timeout (1us). I do not know any other possibly better solution now.

Note: you should check also the return value of `ioctlsocket` for possible error.

I will provide my code sample later today.

UPDATE (adding code as promised):

```
/* define list of sockets for function select(..) */
fd_set readfds;
/* define timeout for function select(..) */
TIMEVAL tv;
/* timeout: 1us */
tv.tv_usec = 1;
/* timeout: 0s */
tv.tv_sec = 0;
/* just 1 socket is used */
readfds.fd_count = 1;
readfds.fd_array[0] = receivingSocket;
/* determine the status of one or more sockets with timeout */
int selectReturnValue = select(0, &readfds, 0, 0, &tv);
/* check return value of the call of function select(..) */
switch (selectReturnValue)
{
  /* select(..) function timeout */
  case 0:
    /* time limit expired */
    break;
  /* select(..) function error */
  case SOCKET_ERROR:
    /* check the error status for the last windows sockets operation */
    selectError(WSAGetLastError());
    break;
  /* no timeout and no error */
  default:
    /* receive data from UDP */
    resultOfrecvfrom = recvfrom(receivingSocket, receivingBuffer, sizeof(receivingBuffer), 0, (SOCKADDR *)&serverReceptionInfo, &serverReceptionInfoLength);
    /* check result of call of recvfrom(..) */
    switch (resultOfrecvfrom)
    {
      /* connection has been gracefully closed  */
      case 0:
        /* socket was closed */
        break;
      /* socket error occurred during last call of socket operation */
      case SOCKET_ERROR:
        /* check the error status for the last Windows Sockets operation */
        recvfromError(WSAGetLastError());
        break;
      /* resultOfrecvfrom amount of data received */
      default:            
        /* ... add your code here */
        break;
    }
    break;      
}
```

I just copied crucial part of my code if more is needed, let me know in comments.